# Delete substrings in pandas DataFrame with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I want my python script to delete a row in a DataFrame, if the term at the current index is a substring of the following term. And also, if the following term is a substring of the term at the current index.

In the following example only the last data set with the terms 'A 600 Strom' should be left aswell as 'Silent'.

```
    term            timestamp
83  A 6             2018-09-27 18:26:46
85  A 60            2018-09-27 18:26:46
86  A 600           2018-09-27 18:26:46
89  A 600           2018-09-27 18:26:47
91  A 600 S         2018-09-27 18:26:47
93  A 600 Str       2018-09-27 18:26:48
95  A 600 Stro      2018-09-27 18:26:49
97  A 600 Str       2018-09-27 18:26:53
98  A 600 Strom     2018-09-27 18:26:5
99  S               2018-09-27 18:26:48
100 Sil             2018-09-27 18:26:49
101 Silen           2018-09-27 18:26:53
102 Silent          2018-09-27 18:26:5
```

Is there an elegant and efficient solution or do I have to process a series of if-statements in a loop?

Comment: is the term always in the same format `A 600 Storm` i.e `B 250 Rain` and `B 2` would be a subset of it

Comment: it is not. It could also be something like "weather" and "weat" would be a subset. 

For a better understanding: The data comes from an application that gathers all search queries from the users, so the term could be in any format

Comment: is there a user key in the table?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it is inconsistent and therefore not really usable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to shift the `term` column and assign it to the new_column `s_1` then use [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) along `axis=1` to create a boolean `mask` by comparing a previous term to next term`(s_1)` and also compare the next term`(s_1)` to its previous term. Finally use this `mask` to filter the dataframe:

```
mask = (
    df.assign(s_1=df['term'].shift(-1).astype(str))
    .agg(lambda s: s['term'] in s['s_1'] or s['s_1'] in s['term'], axis=1)
)

df1 = df[~mask]
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
           term            timestamp
98  A 600 Strom  2018-09-27 18:26:53
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!